# Azure Powershell - How to upload file to Blob Storage using "write-only" shared access signature (SAS)?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I've been trying this for some time now. Here's my Powershell:

```
$storSas = "sas-generated-with-windows-storage-explorer"
$StorageAccountName = "storageacc"
$containerName = "some-cont-name"
$clientContext = New-AzureStorageContext -SasToken $storSAS -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName

# upload a file
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File "F:\somefile" `
  -Container $containerName `
  -Blob "somefile" `
  -Context $ClientContext
```

And every time I get:

> > The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. HTTP Status Code: 403 - HTTP Error Message: This re
> >     quest is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

My policy has Write and List permissions, why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

1. Please use the latest Azure Powershell from https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases (currently is 6.9.0)
2. If you need upload blob with SAS without Read permission, need add `-Force`to `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent` cmdlets. This is because by default we will check if the dest blob exist (need read permission), and remind user weather to overwrite if dest blob exist.

The following script works for me: 

`$sas = New-AzureStorageBlobSASToken -container $containerName -Blob $blobname -Permission w -Context $ctxkey
$ctxsas = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -SasToken $sas
$a = Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $localSrcFile -Container $containerName -Blob $blobname -Force -Context $ctxsas`

Besides that, if you use the latest version of Azure Powershell, Get-AzureStorageContainer also works with SAS. (Anyway, container ACL can't be get since need key permission)